# single sign on with adfs is not working for http redirect

Tags: single-sign-on, authentication

When I'm set Service Provider Initiated Request Binding to http post it's working. But when I'm set Service Provider Initiated Request Binding to http redirect it's not working (It shows certificate  error ). I need to set http redirect because we need to enable sso for ipad also.